# How to negate predicates?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

How can I go about negating predicates? It's asking me to shift a negation in as far inside the predicate as possible.

$$\forall x ((x \ge 100) \lor (x < 100))$$

I am quite new to discrete mathematics so would greatly appreciate a walkthrough. Thanks!

Comment: $ \neg \forall x.P(x) \iff \exists x.\neg P(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

$$\forall \to \;\;\exists $$
$$\ge \to \;\;<$$
$$\lor \to \;\;\land $$

so the negation is

$$\exists x \;: x <100 \;\; \land \;\; x\ge 100$$

> remark

Your proposition is always true (tautology), thus its negation is always false (contradiction).

Answer (score 1):

If you jut want the symbol which represents logical negation, you can visit [Wikipedia's symbology page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbolsv) and see that you can use either

$$!$$

Or

$$¬$$